# Implementing LSTM based Siamese NN architecture

Tags: python, keras-2

Problem is to compare a given student answer to faculty given the modal answer or correct answer and assign grades to the student answer. After researching a lot, Siamese architecture with LSTMs seems to be a very good choice for the neural network architecture as the problem is highly similar to finding textual similarity between two pairs of sentences. 
I have currently adopted the simplest architecture with one embedding layer that uses pre-trained word2vec model, adds LSTM on top of the embedding with many-to-one architecture and then using cosine similarity to compute the similarity between the correct answer and student given answer.

Model creation seems fine but I have problem while merging the two LSTMs using cosine similariy measure

Here is my code..

```
true_ans_model = Sequential()
true_ans_model.add(Embedding(nbwords+1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights= weightMatrixWithPadding], mask_zero=True, trainable=False ))
x_left = true_ans_model.add(LSTM(MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH,return_sequences=False))

stud_ans_model = Sequential()
stud_ans_model.add(Embedding(nbwords+1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[weightMatrixWithPadding], mask_zero=True, trainable=False ))
stud_ans_model.add(LSTM(MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH, return_sequences=False))

merge_lstms = merge([x_left, x_right], mode='cos', dot_axes=1)
```

Here is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
   418             try:
--> 419                 K.is_keras_tensor(x)
420             except ValueError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in is_keras_tensor(x)
392                           tf.SparseTensor)):
--> 393         raise ValueError('Unexpectedly found an instance of type `' + str(type(x)) + '`. '
394                          'Expected a symbolic tensor instance.')

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'NoneType'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in is_keras_tensor(x)
392                           tf.SparseTensor)):
--> 393         raise ValueError('Unexpectedly found an instance of type `' + str(type(x)) + '`. '
 394                          'Expected a symbolic tensor instance.')

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'NoneType'>`. 
Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-41-7a6e14b23349> in <module>()
----> 1 merge_lstms = merge([x_left, x_right], mode='cos', dot_axes=1)
  #final_layer = dot([x_left,x_right], axes=1, normalize=True)
  predictions = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(final_layer)

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\layers.py in merge(inputs, mode, concat_axis, dot_axes, output_shape, output_mask, arguments, name)
  466                             arguments=arguments,
  467                             name=name)
--> 468         return merge_layer(inputs)
  469 
470 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
550                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
551                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 552                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
553 
554                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    423                                  'Received type: ' +
    424                                  str(type(x)) + '. Full input: ' +
--> 425                                  str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the 
layer '
    426                                  'should be tensors.')


ValueError: Layer merge_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'NoneType'>. Full input: [None, None]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```